# rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(605):

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, rsync

I get the following error:

```
    sudo ionice -c 3 nice -n +19 rsync -av --progress -e 'ionice -c 3 nice -n +19 ssh -l root -p 22 192.168.0.1' 192.168.0.1:/domains/remote/. /domains/local/;
root@192.168.0.1's password:
bash: 192.168.0.1: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

rsync worked earlier, now I get this error.

EDIT1:

```
root@local-debian7:/root# rsync -av --progress -e 'ssh -l root -p 22 192.168.0.1' 192.168.0.1:/domains/remote/. /domains/local/;
root@192.168.0.1's password:
bash: 192.168.0.1: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

Still the same after simplifying.

EDIT2:

```
rsync -av --progress -e 'ssh -l root -p 22' 192.168.0.1:/domains/remote/. /domains/local/;
```

After removing first 192.168.0.1 in -e part, finally successfully works!

Thanks to @andrew-domaszek!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `192.168.0.1` from the -e string.

Comment: Your solution helped! Now works!

Answer (score 12):

The error is quite clear: one of the remote command/program (most probably `rsync`) is not found. Can you double-check that `rsync` is installed on the remote machine and that the `PATH` variable is correctly configured?

Anyway, your `rsync` command seems unnecessarily complex: try running something as

`rsync -avn --progress root@192.168.0.1:/domains/remote/ /domains/local/`

Does it change anything?

Comment: `192.168.0.1` is the command that's not found. It thinks that is the command. Andrew's answer is right.

Comment: @shodanshok solution is correct. If the remote host doen't have rsync installed, then source host can't sync with remote host source host will stop syncing.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full paths to `nice`, `ionice` and `ssh` in the `-e` block. Something is not in the path more than likely.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case the problem was missing rsync on the remote linux.
Once I installed rsync on the remote machine, rsync works like a charm.